# How to override non-virtual functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, virtual

The very new syntax of `override` allows to let the compiler to report an error, if one does not really *override* a virtual function [N3206](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3206.htm).

```
class Base {
    virtual void vfunc();
    void afunc();
};
```

The following cases will be an error in `class Derived : public Base`, as mentioned in the Std examples:

- `void vfunk() override;       // err: typo`
- `void vfunc(int) override;    // err: argument`
- `void vfunc() const override; // err: cv`

But what if the base method is **not virtual**?

- `void afunk() override;  // ?`
- `void afunc(int) override;  // ?`
- `void afunc() const override // ?;`

Comment: ..how is `void vfunk() override;` a typo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spec draft (n3242) says

> If a virtual function is marked with the virt-speciﬁer override and does not override a member function of a base class, the program is ill-formed.

Since the function declarations you show are not virtual, you also run afoul of

> A virt-specifier-seq shall contain at most one of each virt-specifier. The virt-specifiers override and final shall only appear in the declaration of a virtual member function.

Note that a function that has the same name and parameter list (including constness) as a base function, but that is *not* virtual does *not* override that base function. It is instead said to *hide* the base function.

Designating that a function hides a base function by putting `new` instead of `override` after the function's declaration was part of the C++0x draft, but will not be part of C++0x as there were problems with finding syntax spots for non-function members for putting `new` at, in time. Consequently, it was voted out for C++0x.

Comment: How right you are. I only looked into the change proposal, and overlooked it. Thx.